# Import URL return values

Tags: t-sql, url

I'm trying to import data from a quantum random number generator and load it into a table:
https://qrng.anu.edu.au/API/jsonI.php?length=10&type=uint8&size=1

The results, if you were to run the URL in a browser, look exactly like this:

{"type":"uint8","length":10,"data":[76,104,98,90,47,116,250,86,43,108],"success":true}

It's just a string return that I can easily parse...but all I see when searching for how to do this is XML and JSON stuff.  I don't need that.  I just want to execute a simple URL and parse the string return value...but it's got me stumped.

Comment: Your question its not enough clear. what's your mean tsql tag? please read how to ask good question in help center for give good feedback

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided enough sample data to offer a complete answer but here's some sample code that will get you close:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(8000) = 'https://qrng.anu.edu.au/API/jsonI.php?length=10&type=uint8&size=1';

SELECT NewString = 
'{'+STRING_AGG(CONCAT('"',SUBSTRING(s.Item,1,idx.N-1),'":')+
  ISNULL(CAST(TRY_CAST(f.S AS INT) AS VARCHAR(8000)), CONCAT('"',f.S,'"')),',')+'}'

FROM        (VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string,CHARINDEX('?',@string)+1,8000))) AS ns(NewString)
CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(ns.NewString,'&')                     AS s
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('=',s.Item)))                            AS idx(N)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(s.Item,idx.N+1,8000)))                   AS f(S);
```

**Returns:**

```
{"length":10,"type":"uint8","size":1}
```